# Understanding precedence when assigning and testing for definedness in Perl

Tags: perl, variable-assignment, operator-precedence, defined

When trying to assign a variable and test it for definedness in one operation in Perl, as would be useful for instance in an `if`'s condition, it would seem natural to me to write:

```perl
if ( defined my $thing = $object->get_thing ) {
    $thing->do_something;
}
```

As far as my understanding goes, `defined` has the precedence of a [rightward list operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#List-Operators-%28Rightward%29), which is lower than that of the assignment, therefore I would expect my code above to be equivalent to:

```perl
if ( defined ( my $thing = $object->get_thing ) ) {
    $thing->do_something;
}
```

While the latter, parenthesised code does work, the former yields the following fatal error: "Can't modify defined operator in scalar assignment".

It's not a big deal having to add parentheses, but I would love to understand why the first version doesn't work, e.g. what kind of "thing" `defined` is and what is its precedence?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Named operators are divided into *unary operators* (operators that always take exactly one operand) and *list operators* (everything else)<sup>[1]</sup>.

`defined` and `my`<sup>[2]</sup> are *unary operators*, which have much higher precedence than other named operators.

The same goes for subs, so I'll use them to demonstrate.

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse,-p -e'sub f :lvalue {}  sub g :lvalue {}  f g $x = 123;'
sub f : lvalue { }
sub g : lvalue { }
f(g(($x = 123)));
-e syntax OK

$ perl -MO=Deparse,-p -e'sub f($) :lvalue {}  sub g($) :lvalue {}  f g $x = 123;'
sub f ($) : lvalue { }
sub g ($) : lvalue { }
(f(g($x)) = 123);
-e syntax OK
```

But of course, `defined` is not an lvalue function, so finding it on the LHS of an assignment results in an error.

---

1. `and`, `or`, `not`, `xor`, `lt`, `le`, `gt`, `ge`, `eq`, `ne` and `cmp` are not considered named operators.
2. `my` is very unusual. Aside from having both a compile-time and run-time effect, its syntax varies depending on whether parens are used around its argument(s) or not. Without parens, it's a unary operator. With parens, it's a list operator.

Comment: Do you know what determines that `defined` has higher precedence than assignment? For instance, `print my $test = 'test'` does print "test".

Comment: @scozy: don't think of 'my' as an operator with precedence. The keyword 'my' induces a special parsing.

Comment: @gensym, That makes no sense. Keyword requiring special parsing is pretty much the very definition of an operator. (The only bit missing is "usable in an expression".) Furthermore, saying "consider `my` is special" doesn't help since the question is asking how do `my` and `defined` work given that they are special.